# Create a link to a wordpress photogallery

Tags: wordpress

I have created a photogallery in a wordpress post.

Is there a way to create a link to my photogallery outside of the post?

For example: In my post I insert a gallery. Then, in another page I'd like to recall the same gallery:

```
<a href="[gallery_destination]" >PhotoGallery</a>
```

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no.

You could recreate the gallery on a post which only contains that gallery. And link to that.

Is there a reason why you don't want to link to the whole post.